# Lerp.localScale is not working OnTriggerEnter,Unity5.3.3,Gear VR App Dev

Tags: javascript, triggers, unity-game-engine, gear-vr, lerp

I am buliding a Gear VR APP,I want my character to scale down on entering the box collider zone,I can scale it down all of sudden by using transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.3F,0.3F,0.3F); But i want it to be done smoothly.Dont knw the reason why its not picking up this lerp line??Can any one helpp???I tagged my box collider(cube to "Mani") and one thing more,OnTriggerExit my lerp one is also not calling.

```
#pragma strict

var newScale : Vector3 = Vector3 (0.1,0.1,0.1);

var Grow : Vector3 = Vector3 (1,1,1);
var speed : float =2.0;

function Start () {
  transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F,1F,1F);
}

function Update () {

} 

function OnTriggerEnter (info : Collider) { 

  if(info.tag == "Mani") { 
    transform.localScale =Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, newScale, speed * Time.deltaTime/2);
    //transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.3F,0.3F,0.3F);
    Debug.Log("Player hit new cube");
  }

}


function OnTriggerExit (Col : Collider) { 

  if(Col.tag == "Mani") { 
     //    transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 1F, transform.localScale.y);
     transform.localScale =Vector3.Lerp(newScale, Grow, speed * Time.deltaTime); //transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F,1F,1F); Debug.Log("Player left cube");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand what Lerp does. Lerp does not animate anything by itself, it only interpolates between two values by t, where t is in the range of 0 to 1. You can imagine t as percentage -> if t is 0, the result of lerp is the first value (or in case of v3 also 0% in the direction of the 2nd), if t is 1 the result is the second, if t is 0.5 the result lies in the middle of both, so if its 0.25 its at 25% (Slerp is basically the same, only that the value represents a rotation, check wikipedia for more infos on all that).

But what does that mean for you in the end?

You need to call Lerp multiple times, and set t to where you are in time. One option would be to start a coroutine and gradually in-/decrease t by `(1 / seconds) * Time.deltaTime` each frame once the player enters/exits the trigger.

edit:

Attach this to a visible gameobject and run it. It think it should clear up how Lerp works. The important part is **t**. it needs to in-/decrease over time to have an animation effect.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LerpExample : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 targetScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    public float duration = 2;

    Vector3 originalScale;
    float timeFactor;
    float t; 

    void Start() {
        originalScale = transform.localScale;

        //since only values between 0 and 1 will do something
        //we need to know "how much" Time.deltaTime affects our lerping
        //ofc we could calculate it "on the fly", but it stays the same so better store it
        timeFactor = 1 / duration;

        t = 0;
    }

    void Update() {

        //this is just so it repeats over and over
        //if t would grow bigger than 1, it would just be interpreted as 1 by Lerp
        if (t > 1) t -= 1;

        //this is what animates it in the end. each frame (its the update method!) a fraction gets added to t. think of it as percentage.
        t += timeFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, targetScale, t);

    }
}
```

edit2: alright, this is the above running in a coroutine. theres a small "trap" though. i didnt account for when the player leaves the trigger before the scaling ended. if he does, the duration is inconsistent. if for example its 10s and he leaves after 2s, he will scale back to normal over 10, not 2 seconds. i leave that up to you to fix if you want it fixed.

this goes onto the trigger

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Cake : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 targetScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    public float duration = 2;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Alice alice = other.GetComponentInParent<Alice>();
        if (alice == null) return;
        alice.Eat(this);
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        Alice alice = other.GetComponentInParent<Alice>();
        if (alice == null) return;
        alice.GrowBackToNormal(this);
    }

}
```

and this goes onto the object entering the trigger

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Alice : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 originalScale;
    Coroutine eatAllTheCakeCoroutine;

    void Start() {
        originalScale = transform.localScale;
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeScale(Vector3 targetScale, float duration) {
        Vector3 startScale = transform.localScale;
        float timeFactor = 1 / duration;
        float t = 0;
        while (t < 1) {
            t += timeFactor * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, targetScale, t);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.localScale = targetScale;
    }

    public void Eat(Cake cake) {
        if (eatAllTheCakeCoroutine != null) StopCoroutine(eatAllTheCakeCoroutine);
        eatAllTheCakeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ChangeScale(cake.targetScale, cake.duration));

    }
    public void GrowBackToNormal(Cake cake) {
        if(eatAllTheCakeCoroutine != null) StopCoroutine(eatAllTheCakeCoroutine);
        eatAllTheCakeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ChangeScale(originalScale, cake.duration));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou soo much YES, there was a stupid error,A line of code was placed inthe start function which wasnt letting the lerp function to do its job. function Start () { //transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F,1F,1F);// this was the stupid line. //--------------------------

Comment: Now My ontriggerEnter and Exit r working but when i active the On trigger exit line of code,my OVR charcters starts to shake inside trigger zone //------ function OnTriggerStay (info : Collider) { if(info.tag == "Mani1") { transform.localScale =Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, newScale, speed * Time.deltaTime);

     //transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.9F,0.9F,0.9F);
     Debug.Log("Player Mani1");
     }

} //-----------

function OnTriggerExit (info : Collider) { if(info.tag == "Mani1") { transform.localScale =Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, Grow, speed * Time.deltaTime);

}

}

Comment: you need to increase t (the 3rd argument of lerp). its supposed to go from 0 to 1 while you scale. in the 1st frame t should be 0, in the next you increase it by `(1 / seconds) * TimeDeltaTime`, and you keep increasing each consequent frame until you hit 1. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html maybe also this tutorial helps you http://www.blueraja.com/blog/404/how-to-use-unity-3ds-linear-interpolation-vector3-lerp-correctly

Comment: the reason why it seems to be shaking is that you set the t parameter of lerp to almost the same value each frame. almost because you multiply speed by Time.deltaTime, and Time.deltaTime is about 0.01667s because the framerate is not a 100% stable. if the above tutorial doesnt help, im going to write up some code for you :D

Comment: Didnt get it ;(..Am sorry am still in my learning phase.What to change in this piece of code??

  transform.localScale =Vector3.Lerp(newScale, Grow, speed * Time.deltaTime);

 //transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F,1F,1F); Debug.Log("Player left cube");
  }

Comment: gimme an hour or so then ill be home and write something up for you.

Comment: @Maryam Bakhtawar sorry it took so long, i was held up at work. i edited an example in, i hope this clears up the behaviour of Lerp. im sorry if you expected a full behavior, but that would be a bit much.

Comment: I failed to achieve what i wanted to,could not set this function fr triggers.It will be a great help if u solve it for my on triiggerStay and exit

Comment: @MaryamBakhtawar oh man, well here you go, i edited it to fit.

Comment: Why r u soo awsome??WHYYY??
Thankyou so very much yes for solving this problem and taking out ur precious time fr my post.You R AWSOME

Bless You.